# I can't wrap the anchor tags of .nivo-controlNav (Nivo slider) using jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I want to wrap this: [nivo-controlNav a](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/) with `<span>` tags.

**js/custom.js:**

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function() {
 $j(".nivo-controlNav a").wrap("<span></span>");
});
```

**header.php:**

```
 <!-- Include the Nivo Slider JS file -->
 <script src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/js/nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/PIE.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/custom.js"></script>
 <!-- Set up the Nivo Slider -->
 <script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(window).load(function() {
  jQuery('#slider').nivoSlider();
 });
 </script>
</head>
```

But it doesn't work.

I tried this:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function() {
 $j("h2").wrap("<span></span>");
});
```

and it did work.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check it maybe it's work for you.

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function() {
 $j(".nivo-controlNav a").wrap("<span/>");
});
```